# Can't attach to windows service process

Tags: c#, debugging, service, windows-services

I built a windows service on my machine and I'm able to attach to the process using `Debugger.Launch()` I posted the source to our source control repo (visual source safe) and got latest on another machine. When I run the service on the 2nd machine, the dialog pops up to select a debugger IDE (Visual Studio 2010) and then the attach dialog appears, I click attach.. and it never brings up the source code. I did get latest on the 2nd machine so the source is there. The paths aren't identical on both machines, I don't know if that's a/the problem.

Original machine source path:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\brsande\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SBAnetMigrationService
```

2nd Machine source path:

```
D:\Documents and Settings\brsande\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SBAnetMigrationService.root\SBAnetMigrationService
```

I've looked at a handful of questions regarding the inability of people to attach to their process but it seems most of them didn't know about the `Debugger.Launch()` method. Are my paths the issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are the .pdb files in the same directory as the executable on the 2nd machine?

Comment: No, had no idea what those were even for, throw those in the EXE dir?

Comment: Yeah.  Those are the files which contain the debugging symbols which allow mapping of the binary (compiled) files back to source code.  Without them, all you can see is the assembly (or possibly IL) code, which won't help.

Comment: Ok @Bobson I tried putting those pdbs in the exe path and ran the service, still didn't bring up the source on Debugger.Launch(). Any other ideas?

Comment: Not off the top of my head.  They should be in the same directory(s) as their matching DLL files, but there's just so many other things that could be interfering that I don't have anything else to suggest.  Put in lots of logging?

Comment: The exe and DLLs are all in the same directory, I put the pds's in there but still wont load up the code. And I cant just do all the debugging on my original machine because the 2nd machine service is configured to use a Production account which I dont have the password for (so I can't remove it and re-run the installer for example). It would take weeks to get the service configured again (big corporation problems)

Comment: When I build in debug and copy the EXE over, it loads up the code, but doesn't work in release mode. What the ef

Comment: Try http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=a40c0d4f-66d0-4704-94f6-0efda4a44465